# Modify (strech) one object by moving another object

Tags: mesh, modifiers, transforms, vertices

Having 2 cube objects A and B.
I would like the cube B to be stretched if I move A away.
So the object A should be grabbed/linked/connect to some vertices in B.

In this way I do not need to reshape object B (in Edit mode) so it fits together with object A.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use hooks: select B and then A, then go to edit mode (of A).
select the A face near to B and add a hook to selected object (CTRL-H).

Now, when you move B, A will be stretched, since you're thus moving the hooked face of A, through B.

Eg:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get the hook to work in my first attempt. Clearly the process of selection is important. Just Select A and then in edit, Add Modifier Hook, and in the Modifier/Hook select Object B isn't working. You must select object B and then add (shift+right mouse button) object A, (tab) edit Mode.... /Thanks

Comment: correct, that's why I was showing the modifier pane aside, it helps to better handle more complicated setups without worrying about selection orders... :) and also there you can later fine tune hook settings properly. btw, B could also be anything else, and also an empty, if this can help